# How to prove this inequality? $(a+b+c=1)$

Tags: inequality

Show that if $a,b,c$ are positive reals and $a+b+c=1$, then the following must hold:

$$\frac{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{abc}+3 \geq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$$

What I have tried is using $abc \leq \frac{1}{27}$ $(a+b+c \geq 3\sqrt[3]{abc}) $ and multiplying everything by $abc$, but I don'think that's a good idea because $abc$ can be positive and negative.
I have also tried substituting $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 3abc$, but that isn't strong enough.
Any help/hints please??

Comment: This looks like an application of the AM-GM inequality

Comment: Probably, but I have no idea where/how.

Comment: what kind of numbers are $a,b,c$?

Comment: It is not true for $(a,b,c)=(1/2,-1,3/2)$, for example.

Comment: ah.. well it doesn't say anything like $a,b,c \geq 0$. but maybe that's the case?

Comment: Note that $a,b,c$ cannot be $0$ since that makes the expressions undefined. I think $a,b,c$ are positive reals.

Comment: Now you should edit your attempts: $abc>0$, so you can always multiply everything by $abc$. Also $abc\le \frac{1}{27}$, not $\frac{1}{9}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if $a,b,c>0$ then we get 
$$\frac{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{abc}+3\geq \frac{a+b+c}{a}+\frac{a+b+c}{b}+\frac{a+b+c}{c}$$
this is equivalent to
$$\frac{2(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{abc}\geq \frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}$$
and this
$$2(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b)$$ 
and now note that
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\geq ab(a+b)$$

Comment: beautiful!!!!!!

Comment: or rearrangement for last line

Comment: the next problem please, i love inequalities!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, multiply the right-hand side by $a+b+c$, so that both sides are now degree-zero.  Then you want to prove 
$$2a^3+2b^3+2c^3\geq a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2$$

Comment: rearrangement inequality I guess

Comment: @jack Or $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\ge ab(a+b)$ (which is simple to prove -- $a^2-ab+b^2\ge ab\iff (a-b)^2\ge 0$ with equality iff $a=b$). This is actually identical to Sonnhard's solution, except for this last claim.

Comment: What last claim? He uses the same, no?

Comment: @jack Michael doesn't prove it while Sonnhard does.

Comment: you mean the opposite, Michael does prove it

Comment: @jack No, Michael doesn't prove $2(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a^3)\ge \sum_{\text{sym}}a^2b$. Sonnhard does, using $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)\ge ab(a+b)$.

Comment: Ok, I thought you meant with the comments.